# How to assign a value to texbox inside a gridview as itemTemplate

Tags: asp.net, templates, gridview, textbox

i have a gridview with a item Template with a textbox, so i create a datatable in memory and assign to the gridview, but the values doesn't assign to the textbox in the item template.

How i assign a value of my datatable to the control inside grid.

```
grdNotas.Rows(numero).Cells(2).FindControl("txtf1")
```

doesn't put the property of text.

```
Dim tbnotasAlumnos As New DataTable

    For Each fila As DataRow In tbAlumnnoCurso.Rows
        tbnotasAlumnos = conexion.consultaNotaMateriaAQP(tbAlumnnoCurso.Rows(numero)(0).ToString, ddlmaterias.SelectedValue, txtQuimestre.Text, txtparcial.Text)
        'fill the textboxes
        grdNotas.Rows(numero).Cells(2).FindControl("txtf1")
        numero = numero + 1
    Next
```

how i can do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need not only to find the control, but also to cast it to specific type. That will give you an access to textbox's properties

```
Dim txt As TextBox = CType(grdNotas.Rows(numero).Cells(2).FindControl("txtf1"), TextBox)
txt.Text = "value"
```